# React syntax does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, syntax

```
componentDidMount() {
    const restaurants = Restaurant.all()
    restaurants.then( rests => {
        this.setState({
            restaurants: rests
        })
    })
}


render() {
        const { restaurants } = this.state;

        return (
            <main className="SearchRestaurantsPage" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Chosen className="Chosen-select" onChange={ value => console.log(value) }>
                    {    
                        restaurants.map( restaurant => {

                            return restaurant ?
                                ( <option key={restaurant.id}>{ restaurant.name }</option> )
                                :
                                ''
                        })
                    }
                </Chosen>
            </main>
        );
    }
```

I have my react code above and trying to return a mapped array that is supposed to be something like

```
[<option key={1}>first</option>, <option key={2}>two</option>, <option key={3}>three</option>]
```

It works if I put a randomly created array like this,

```
render() {
        const { restaurants } = this.state;

        return (
            <main className="SearchRestaurantsPage" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Chosen className="Chosen-select" onChange={ value => console.log(value) }>
                    {    
                         [<option key={1}>first</option>, <option key={2}>two</option>, <option key={3}>three</option>]
                    }
                </Chosen>
            </main>
        );
    }
```

but no matter what I do with the map method, it just doesn't show anything.
I have already checked there is an array containing elements assigned to this.state.restaurant.

Comment: Are you getting the data for the restaurants from an API?

Comment: are there "undefined" entries or why are you checking `restaurant?` ...

Comment: you said, `this.state.restaurant` but you are taking values from `restaurants `

Comment: Bojan lvanac - Yes, I'm getting the data from an API

Comment: lipp - No, there is no undefined entries, but I just checked to verify if the data is being read properly

Comment: The first thing I would do is add a `console.log(restaurants)` (or a breakpoint) above your `return` statement, to see what's there. Note that since this is `render()`, it's expected to be hit multiple times.

Comment: Rohith Murali - They are the same since I destructively assigned as const { restaurants } = this.state

Comment: I think the problem is related to the life cycle method componentDidMount(), but I have no idea how to solve that.

Comment: can anyone please explain how the rendering works in this case..?

Comment: @JayJeong `const { restaurants } = this.state ` would work only if already the object in state is `restaurants` and not `restaurant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called after the first `render`. Consequently your `restaurants` is undefined when the first `render` processed.

You can check if `restaurants` exists in render method:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const restaurants = Restaurant.all()
    restaurants.then( rests => {
        this.setState({
            restaurants: rests
        })
    })
}


render() {
        const { restaurants } = this.state;

        return (
            <main className="SearchRestaurantsPage" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Chosen className="Chosen-select" onChange={ value => console.log(value) }>
                    {    
                        restaurants && restaurants.map( restaurant => {

                            return restaurant ?
                                ( <option key={restaurant.id}>{ restaurant.name }</option> )
                                :
                                null
                        })
                    }
                </Chosen>
            </main>
        );
    }
```

Also, check if your state is defined in the constructor or as the class property.

So the whole component could be the follow:

```js
class Rests extends React.Component {    
    state = {restaurants: null};

    componentDidMount() {
        const restaurants = Restaurant.all()
        restaurants.then( rests => {
            this.setState({
                restaurants: rests
            })
        })
    }


    render() {
        const { restaurants } = this.state;

        if (!restaurants) {
           return null; // or you can return <LoadingSpinner /> here
        }

        return (
            <main className="SearchRestaurantsPage" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Chosen className="Chosen-select" onChange={ value => console.log(value) }>
                    {    
                        restaurants.map( restaurant => {

                            return restaurant ?
                                ( <option key={restaurant.id}>{ restaurant.name }</option> )
                                :
                                null
                        })
                    }
                </Chosen>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

In the last example, we render nothing if there is no any data in `restaurants`. After we fetch data we rerender component and show options to users

Comment: You are right, I just have noticed that too, but I don't know how to put the data before it renders the first time.

Comment: I also have tried componentWillMount, but doesn't work..:( I don't know what to do

Comment: It's not necessary to put the data before component inited. You can render nothing or loader spinner if data don't exist.

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated method. And render doesn't wait for data fetching or any other async actions

Comment: I see.. what could be the solution for this?

Comment: I extended the solution in my answer

Comment: I thought it would definitely work, but somehow it does not render again, it still can't find the data

Comment: nevermind genius, it actually works as I used null instead of an empty array which I used before. thanks so much.

Comment: but why wouldn't using an empty array in constructor instead of null work ? 
like so:
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.state = {
      restaurants: [ ]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be where you declared the restaurent constant from the state. I've written a sample code that works below.

```
import React from 'react';

const restaurentData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name 3'
  }
]
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      restaurents: restaurentData
    }
  }

  render () {
    const restaurents = this.state.restaurents;
    return (
      <ul>
        {restaurents.map(restaurent => {
          return restaurent 
            ? (<li key={restaurent.id}>{`${restaurent.id} -- ${restaurent.name}`} </li>) 
            : null;
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default Hello;
```